# Is there an equivalent of the VBA function Cells on the worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to use index numbers to refer to specific cells, like how in VBA you can use `Cells(3,2)` to refer to cell C2.

I was hoping `"=CELLS(3,2)"` would work, but, sadly, that doesn't appear to exist. Is there another way to do that?

**EDIT:**

I should clarify that I need to use this inside of a SUM() worksheet function, so it would need to return the cell reference, not the value inside the cell.

Comment: `=OFFSET(A1,3-1,2-1)`  or `=INDEX(A1:E10,3,2)`

Comment: @TimWilliams has got it, but here's another fun way to get the value from C2: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,3))`

Comment: I'm trying to do `=(SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0):OFFSET(A1,12,0)))`, where A 1 to A12 are filled with random numbers, and it's not working. Do I have to use another reference style?

Comment: OFFSET() should be returning a cell reference, not the values inside the cells, right?

Comment: `=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0,12,1))` There are two additional parameters you can pass to offset which determine #rows and #columns of the returned range. Like doing `Offset(0,0).Resize(1,12)` in VBA

Comment: So it's saying to select 12 rows and 1 column? Will that always be selected down and to the right, if, say, I put the column # as two?

Comment: Also, can you put this in an answer, so I can checkmark you? You got my code working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `OFFSET(original_range,rowsOffset,colOffset)` formula to get a reference to a range which is some specific offset from a point on the sheet.

There are also two additional parameters you can pass to offset which determine #rows and #columns of the returned range:

`=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0,12,1))`

will give you a range 12 rows by 1 column starting at A1.

`=SUM(OFFSET(A1,2,2,12,1))`  would start at C3

Like doing `Offset(r,c).Resize(12,1)` in VBA

Answer (score 2):

You could change the reference style... I often prefer the R1C1 reference style for certain functions I'm writing.

Here's a link that shows how to get to it:
http://www.excelqa.info/2010/12/06/switch-to-r1c1-reference-style-in-excel-2010/

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a custom formula to handle that.

```
    Public Function customFunction(a As Integer, b As Integer, Optional sh As String)
If sh <> "" Then
    customFunction = Sheets(sh).Cells(a, b).Value
Else
    customFunction = Cells(a, b).Value
End If
    End Function
```